# Pandas - Select multiple columns from a nested header after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Say I have the following dataset :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a'   : [1, 1, 3],
               'b'   : [4, 5, 6],
               'c'   : [7, 8, 9],
               'cat' : ['a', 'a', 'b']})

df 

cat = df.groupby('cat')

ag = cat.agg({ "a" : ["sum", "mean"],
           "b" : "count",
           "c" : "mean"})

print(ag)

      a        b     c
      sum mean count mean
cat                    
a     2    1     2   7.50
b     3    3     1   9.00
```

I'd like to return a DataFrame containing `(a,sum)` and `(b,count)` for `(cat==a)`. How would I do that without flattening the headers

```
      a    b    
      sum  count
cat                    
a     2      2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.xs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) with `axis=1`:

```
res = ag.xs([('a', 'sum'), ('b', 'count')], axis=1)

print(res)

      a     b
    sum count
cat          
a     2     2
b     3     1
```

Comment: Thanks, I believe I can use `loc()` or `axis=0` to further restrict the rows by `cat==0` ? is there any preference ?

Comment: I prefer to chain with `.loc[['a', 'b']]` or `.loc['b']` etc in this case.